# Why am I getting "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()" when dealing with a list?

Tags: python, list

I am storing the number of times a label with value i appears in a list: labels_list. For some reason I am getting the Value Error mentioned in the title? Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

```
for i in range(10):
     count = labels_list.count(i)
     count_values.append(count)
```

Comment: Please add sample data for `labels_list` to your question.

Answer (score 0):

With the comments clarification I assumed we have 2 lists one as a reference of the labels containing the shortest distance and one to be evaluated.

Instead of using a range of integer which will evaluate to an index I'm trying to compare the actual contents of the lists:

I assumed a basic example

```
labels_list = ["a","1","ge","5","th","9","qw"]
list_to_examine = ["1", "22", "rt", "qs", "ge", "1"]
count_values = []

for i in range(len(labels_list)):
    count = list_to_examine.count(labels_list[i])
    count_values.append(count)

print(count_values)
```

I hope it helps leading you on right direction

Comment: Hello Richard, you assumed correctly with your sample input in both lists. Basically, given a shape (M, N) array of distances between M-unlabeled and N-labeled images, and N labels, I need to predict a label for each of the M images based on its k-nearest neighbors. With the snippet I provided, I am attempting to create a list "count_values" that contains the number of times a label with value i appears in labels_list. Labels_list is a list that contains k labels that correspond to the lowest distance values in a list of distances "dists." The line "count = labels_list.count(i)" errors.

Comment: Thank for the explanation, that does helps =) can you show a print on what are the contents of labels_list, I'm thinking that in my example is working because all values are ints, but if the type is different that might be the reason of the error